# Can a Woman truly fall in love with the Devil? If so, will she go to Heaven or Hell, after her life? Why?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, nietzsche, kierkegaard, love

I'm a Christian Baptist, and this is not a troll, I'm genuinely interested in an honest and in-depth answer, regarding all science and religious philosophy, both mysticism and pragmatism. The question, poetically, is "what is love?" Can a mortal fall in love with an infinite being, lets use the terminology of Youjo Senki: Being-X. Can that mortal fulfill all moral and physical duties of marriage to such a creature, without being a hypocrite or a lunatic? Will the differences in intellect overrule the possibilities of love or rather enhance it? What will such relationship give to both sides? Mainly could this relationship be established with a malicious entity, such as the Devil? Would such a relationship enrich the human psyche or deteriorate it? If it there positive, what would it say about our concepts of Good and Evil?

I believe Nietzsche and Kierkegaard had the most to say about this kind of topic.

Comment: See [Sexual relations with demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexuality_in_Christian_demonology#Sexual_relations)

Comment: I hardly believe that either N or K had any interest in the topic "being in love with demons"

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Having briefly skimmed K's SEP article, I could imagine him having briefly written something on the topic (as an aside to some other religious discourse). But I'm not entirely sure that N even believed in demons, the Devil, or any other metaphysical aspect of Christianity, so I rather doubt an answer based on his philosophy is going to be what OP wants to read.

Comment: OP, is this actually appropriate?

Comment: Hello, generally we ask that you limit a question to, well, a question. Far too broad. I'll just address your first question by suggesting that it seems much more appropriate for [a theological site](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).  This is a Q&A site and isn't really devoted to speculative, ambiguous open-ended questions.

Comment: Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: do i get a vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is largely biased and no one without your subjective body of ideas would be able to answer it, me included.

Instead, this is an answer to the question *what is love*, essentially based on the book *The Art of Loving*, by Erich Fromm, which foundations can be found in the work of most philosophers that addressed the subject.

*Love is essentially an attractive interaction between two individuals, which results from an exchange of largely subjective values*.

It is an exchange of values because love implies giving and receiving.  Most people associate love with receiving (affection, sexual pleasure, security, money, etc.), but that's only part of the history. Giving is also pleasant because in a healthy relationship, giving causes the other to react in a non-linear manner, and return more than received.

This is a quite silly but useful example. Suppose I love my wife, so I feel giving her a kiss, so I do it. Since we have a healthy relationship, she feels pleased with the kiss and feels the need to respond giving more than received (the causal reaction is innate to human interactions). So, she give me two kisses. I feel extremely pleased, so I need to react, with something that exceeds what I received. So I give her four kisses. Etc.

That leads to the other part of the concept: when an individual receive more than what given from someone, the individual will feel attracted to that other. This is quite evident. If you go to the supermarket, get a delicious apple for a great price, *you will feel attracted to that supermarket*, to that neighborhood, to that way of life.

Attraction produces repetition. Evidently, if I get pain from my wife, I will reject her in order to avoid repetition. But if I receive values that make me feel good, I will feel attracted to her *in order to repeat receiving such values*.

When receiving is not compensated with giving, the relationship gets damaged and will soon break (one side creates rejection, which is enough to break a relationship). If my wife gives me kisses without any reaction from me, she'll soon stop giving them. I know this sounds utilitarian, but that's how it works. We all give things due to our internal need to receive. People who learn to give without receiving, as a permanent life rule, are just applying the fundamentals of the rule in order to get a nice life. But when generous people are not compensated, they get distanced (careful! you want to have generous people around you, and they are not easy to find). We give in order to receive, and only two individuals who know how to permanently give more than received can make a long lasting relationship.

In multiple cases, people need to suffer (usually, when they have suffered during childhood). So, people might choose a harmful partner in order to get satisfied and repeat suffering. That is love for them. That's why the definition includes the word "subjective". Of course, there are a lot of twisted forms of loving exchange (love with the devil fits probably well here).

When you speak about love with the devil, I personally don't imagine how it works. It is difficult to conceive a devilish entity with whom exchange kisses, laugh, listen music, have a drink, get lunch in the grass, go traveling, go biking, cook, make music or have a nice evening, that's quite subjective to your ideas, so you must get your conclusions based on the meaning of love here.